# NXP Flex SPI and spi mem simultaneous read / write

Tags: embedded, linux-device-driver, spi, imx6, imx7

Hi I am trying to figure out - does the Flex SPI controller support simultaneous read / write?

Let me explain what I mean.

I have the device - FPGA - which once it's clocked immediately sends some data on MISO line.

Eg when I want to issue read operation on FPGA I send the following byte stream:(cmd, addr, length)

> MOSI: 0x80 | 0x12 0x34 0x56 | 0x4

> MISO: 0x11 | 0xXX 0xXX 0xXX | data[0]... data[3]

As you can see the 0x11 byte is pushed by the FPGA on the same clock cycle as the first byte on MOSI. This is something like a status that allows to verify the device type. The rest 3 bytes are undefined, data[0]...data[3] is actual data that was requested.

SPI mem framework that is supposed to be used with this controller does not have such a capability (as far as I know) however I am struggling to find out whether the controller itself support something like this.

Any ideas how can I achieve this?

Comment: Ask in the respective public mailing list.

Comment: I was thinking about it, but isn't linux-spi too generic to such a question?

Comment: SPI is always full-duplex, but it is also always completely driven by the master, which controls the clock. For most applications, the slave doesn't know what to transmit until it sees at least the first byte sent by the master. But I guess there may be a protocol where it can send some kind of status byte. Beyond that, your question is unclear.

Comment: What's unclear here? Let me know and I will provide more details if needed. And the target device works exactly as you said, it sends some status data immediately once the master starts the transmission. The problem I'm trying to solve is that the FlexSPI skips these first 4 bytes, and only receives bytes started from data[0]...data[n]. Ofc these first 4 bytes are sent by the device which I confirmed looking at the communication lines through logic analyzer.

Comment: At its heart, all SPI does is clock out some number of bytes while receiving the same amount of data at the same time, no more, no less.  A very low level interface would have a function (let's call it Transfer) Transfer(unsigned int length, char *txdata, char *rxdata).  In your case, you would then have an 8 byte buffer txbuffer initialized with 0x80, 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 and an 8 byte rxbuffer and call Transfer(8, txbuffer, rxbuffer).  You would then find the FPGA status at rxbuffer[0] and FPGA data starting at rxbuffer[4].

Comment: These sorts of things often have a header part and a data part, which are contiguous on the wire but set up differently in registers.  The header part is write only, so if you want the first byte back then you need to set the header length to zero, and have a separate send and receive buffer for the length of the whole transaction.  I have worked on some NXP parts where this is possible.

Comment: Yes, I think it's fine to ask at linux-spi@ as there are a lot of people who are really familiar with what you are talking about. SO is too generic for a such in my opinion.